# redirecting depending on mysql field value

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 fields in mysql called colour1, colour2, colour3 with either a 'red' or 'blue' value. When attendance1 2 & 3 are submitted it saves in mysql then redirects to submitted1.html.

however if value for each field is 'no' I want it to redirect to submitted2.

Comment: You have the redirect, and you have the three values. Maybe I'm just having a bad night, but have you never heard of an if? (Also, while I'm at it, by the HTTP specification, Location is to be specified with a full URL, not a relative one. And, you should check if the indexes of the post array are set before accessing them.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add this above the last header

```
if($_POST['attendance1'] == 'no' && $_POST['attendance2'] == 'no' && $_POST['attendance3'] == 'no'){
    header("Location: otherpage.html");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: please use the full url for the location header.

Comment: Please read: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html.  Absolute URI's are required, so yes it should be /otherpage.html.  To state that a full URL is required is entirely incorrect according to Header Field Definition Standards per W3.

Comment: wrong, you don't know what absolute means:  HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to » Location: ... http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: @JamesL. Dagon is right. 1. What is an absolute URL? "The two forms [relative vs. absolute] are differentiated by the fact that absolute URIs always begin with a scheme name followed by a colon" [1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.2.2) 2. the Location is defined as `Location = "Location" ":" absoluteURI`, see your own link.